# Adding Refresh Header to HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

Hi i'm creating a Cisco Service in C#

According to the CISCO documentation under the HTTP Header Settings:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/all_models/xsi/3_3_4/english/programming/guide/ip334ch5.html#wp1030557
I should be able to automatically refresh the response if i add a refresh header, the time in seconds to wait and the URL to refresh to.

My question is how to i add this header to my C# HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HttpResponseMessage** has a property named [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.headers.aspx) for that purpose:

```
HttpResponseMessage respMsg = ...;
respMsg.Headers.Remove("Refresh");
respMsg.Headers.Add("Refresh", "value");    <<--- insert your desired value here
```

Be aware that if *Headers* already contains a "Refresh" header value, then the new value will be appended to the existing value (it will not overwrite/replace the existing value), hence the invocation of the *Remove* method.